# How do you freeze angular2 versions with systemjs?

Tags: angular, systemjs

This is a noob question, but I'm trying to keep my Angular2 app from breaking every time the team releases a backwards-incompatible change.  I'm using the [strategy from A2 university](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-run-angular-2-in-production-today/) for production deployment, which includes downloading libs (incl. angular2) from the NPM CDN.  I have a package.json file which specifies "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4", but Systemjs seems to be giving me a different version, which broke my app yesterday.  So my question:

How can I freeze NPM CDN component versions using Systemjs?

(I know there are lots and lots of other tools and bundlers out there, but my experience has been it's very hard to keep them compatible with Angular2, so I'd really like to use the recommended (SystemJS - NPM CDN) Angular2 strategy.)

Thanks for any help!

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "awsec",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

And a snippet from my index.html:

```
<!-- Angular core libs -->
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
```

Comment: just don't upgrade the versions in package.json? am I missing something?

Comment: SystemJS is fetching newer versions (RC5) from  NPM at runtime, ignoring the package.json.

Comment: can you show your tsconfig?

Comment: Of course... added.

Comment: Please also add the content of package.json